# Get content of a cell given the row and column numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get the content of a cell given its row and column number. The row and column number are stored in cells (here B1,B2). I know the following solutions work, but they feel a bit hacky.

Sol 1

```
=CELL("contents",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(B1,B2)))
```

Sol 2

```
=CELL("contents",OFFSET($A$1, B1-1,B2-1))
```

Is there no less verbose method? (like =CellValue(row,col) or whatever)?

Edit / Clarification:
I just want to use the excel worksheet formulas. No VBA. In short, I pretty much look for the equivalent of the VBA Cells() method as an excel Formula.

Comment: Can we get a little more context? Are you using just Excel formulas? VBA? Some other method?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You don't need the CELL() part of your formulas:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(B1,B2))
```

or

```
=OFFSET($A$1, B1-1,B2-1)
```

will both work. Note that both `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET` are volatile functions. Volatile functions can slow down calculation because they are calculated at every single recalculation.

Comment: This is useful enough that I'd like to see it edited to have the right number of closing parentheses.

Comment: Given the popularity of this question/answer, it'd be great to have a little sentence here about what a [volatile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx#sectionSection2) is.

Comment: Note that with the second form, depending on $a$1, it is required that you do not move $a$1 in any way in later edits of the sheet.

Comment: `INDIRECT` +`ADDRESS` is the way to go. Excel in my language translates `OFFSET` into 2 words separated by a period. That is the worst (together with umlauts in function names)!

Answer (score 29):

Try   =index(ARRAY, ROW, COLUMN)

where:
Array: select the whole sheet
Row, Column: Your row and column references

That should be easier to understand to those looking at the formula.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while, but here's how I made it dynamic. It doesn't depend on a sorted table.

First I started with a column of state names (Column A) and a column of aircraft in each state (Column B).  (Row 1 is a header row).

Finding the cell that contains the number of aircraft was:

```
=MATCH(MAX($B$2:$B$54),$B$2:$B$54,0)+MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$54))-1
```

I put that into a cell and then gave that cell a name, "StateRow"
Then using the tips from above, I wound up with this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(StateRow,1))
```

This returns the name of the state from the dynamic value in row "StateRow", column 1

Now, as the values in the count column change over time as more data is entered, I always know which state has the most aircraft.