# Create table out of existing table matching a condition

Tags: excel

EDIT: OK, macros are also accepted.

I want to create a table in Excel that extracts the part of a table that matches a certain condition. If possible without using macros. Here is a plot:

```
A      B      C
0      1
6      2
12     3
18     4     10
0      5
6      6
12     7
18     8     26
0      9
6     10
12    11
18    12     42
```

When looking for `26`, this is what I want to obtain:

```
D
5
6
7
8
```

I get the value `D4 = LOOKUP(26;C:C;B:B)` (which at the end results in `D4 = B8`) and then I am trying to get `D3` somehow...

I have tried using `LOOKUP`, and also trying to get the [reference from a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813888/get-content-of-a-cell-given-the-row-and-column-numbers), in this case `D4` and then modify the path out of it, like "copy the value in `B (8-1)`", but I don't know how to do it.

I am also sure that there is a way easier way to do it, but it has been a while since I started thinking about...

Any help will be appreciated

Best,