# How to calculate a stationary average of column data in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Calculating a running/moving average in Excel is obvious. A non-moving (stationary?) average is both harder to implement and trickier to search for!

Specifically, I want to calculate a column of data which is the average of contiguous sets of `x` values from another column, so I can visualise the effects of `x` when compared to the raw data.

The formula I've come up with works, but seems unnecessarily complex:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1+ROW()-MOD(ROW(),$D$1),1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS($D$1+ROW()-MOD(ROW(),$D$1),1)))
```

It uses INDIRECT and ADDRESS to programmatically calculate a cell range that extends from the current row, up to and down to the current set of `x` rows. `x` is specified in D1. Without all the guff, it's just AVERAGE(i-i%x:i+x-i%x), but it looks a lot uglier than that.

Sample data:

```
Raw     Averaged        10
2428    2426.3      
2425    2426.3      
2421    2426.3      
2423    2426.3      
2432    2426.3      
2431    2426.3      
2421    2426.3      
2431    2426.3      
2427    2426.3      
2424    2426        
2426    2426        
2431    2426        
2429    2426
2428    2426
2428    2426        
2424    2426        
2425    2426        
2422    2426        
2420    2426        
2427    2425.5      
2427    2425.5      
2421    2425.5      
2425    2425.5
```

Avenues for a solution that were unsuccessfully explored were [decimation](https://superuser.com/questions/680892/decimating-rows-in-spreadsheet) type questions and specifying cells by [row and column as numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813888/get-content-of-a-cell-given-the-row-and-column-numbers) type questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest formula that I can think of is

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(A:A,(INT((ROW()-1)/$D$1)*$D$1+1),0,$D$1,1))
```

Comment: This is very neat. I replaced the 10's with $D$1 and removed the +1 to get the first row right. `=AVERAGE(OFFSET(A:A,(INT((ROW()-1)/$D$1)*$D$1),0,$D$1,1))`

Comment: Oh yes, didnot realise that. 10.:). Please accept this as right answer if feel so.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cleaner, but relies on a predefined vector of data:

```
={AVERAGE(IF(ROUNDDOWN((ROW(A$2:A$24)-2)/$D$1,0)=ROUNDDOWN((ROW(A2)-2)/$D$1,0),A$2:A$24))}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use this? Is it an array constant or an array formula? What is the significance of A2 and A24?

Comment: It's an array formula. A2 and A24 represent the start and end, respectively, of the vector containing the raw values. And yes, this is an array formula (needs to be entered using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.