# Given cell A6 with a value "B5", how do I get the element at B5 using A6 as imput?

Tags: excel-formula

Column A has cell index values like Z44,A666, etc.

For example, maybe cell A6 has value B5.

How do I write a function that maps input A6 to output which is the value in cell B5?

That is, what function do I use to make

```
=FUNCTION(A6)
```

return the value at B5?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INDIRECT.

`=INDIRECT(A6)`

Reads A6 as string, gets the string 'B5', and then reads the slot B5.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I saw

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813888/get-content-of-a-cell-given-the-row-and-column-numbers

and was trying things like this, but I didn't realize it was so simple.