# How can I compare strings and sort them accordingly using an auto-generated Google Forms response sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

So my goal is to have every name on the roster in column A and then have the names of those who respond (not everyone will respond) in column B. I want column A to sort alphabetically. I want column B (and the corresponding columns with answers (C-E)) to only fall in line if the name matches. Otherwise columns B through E would be left blank. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "fall in line"?

Comment: For example if on my roster are Adam, Brian, and Chris but only Chris responded to the form, I would want it to skip Adam and Brian and go to the 3rd row and put Chris' name and his form responses, as the name he input in the form would match the name listed on the roster.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new sheet with the roster names. After typing them, use the Google Sheets sorting tools to sort them.

Use the `match` function to identify the corresponding row in the first sheet for each of the roster names.

Once you have got the row, you can get the data for any cells in that row. See [Get content of a cell given the row and column numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813888/get-content-of-a-cell-given-the-row-and-column-numbers) .

Comment: with the match function - how is one able to cross-reference between sheets?

Comment: `Sheet_name!Cell_address` ( see https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/08/excel-reference-another-sheet-workbook/ )